# Can not find mpirxx.h after building the mpir-2.6.0 library in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, gmp

I need to use `mpir-2.6.0` library with `visual c++ 2010`. My code is going to be in c++.

I extracted both folders (`mpir-2.6.0` and `vsyasm-1.2.0-win32`). Then, I copied the content of the folder `vsyasm-1.2.0-win32` (including `vsyasm.exe` after renaming it to `yasm.exe` and placing it in: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\`. Then, I opened the project: `mpir.sln` which is placed in: `\mpir-2.6.0\build.vc10`. Then, I changed the Project configuration to: `Release`.

When I try to build the whole solution, I get a lot of errors such as:

```
error C1020: unexpected #endif  c:\proj\mpir-2.6.0\mpir-2.6.0\mpir.h    4   1   lib_mpir_gc
error C1020: unexpected #endif  c:\proj\mpir-2.6.0\mpir-2.6.0\mpir.h    4   1   lib_mpir_gc
error C1020: unexpected #endif  c:\proj\mpir-2.6.0\mpir-2.6.0\mpir.h    4   1   lib_mpir_gc
```

But when I build every library separately, it is successful.

After the build, I went to: `\mpir-2.6.0\build.vc10\Win32\Release`
and find the files:

```
mpir.lib
mpirxx.lib
mpir.pdb
mpirxx.pdb
```

But I can not find the files:

```
mpir.h
mpirxx.h
```

Which I need to copy them the visual studio include file.

My main source for these configuration is: http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/ (but this was for old versions for the library and the ysam). I do not understand the reasons for these errors. I was able to configure the library with old version. But I need to upgrade as there are improvements in the library and mine is very old one.

Comment: The header file will be somewhere in the source installation, and you will have to add its location to the INCLUDE directories in the Visual Studio setup. I can't give the exact details. Try "dir /s mpir.h" in some likely places (worst case in "c:\")

Comment: I already did search about it but could not find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The output files are now located in mpir\lib\Win32\Release or mpir\dll\Win32\Release.

The recommended way to build MPIR specifcally for your CPU is to first run mpir_config.py which is located in the build.vc10 directory. mpir_config.py will prompt you with a list of CPU options. Then when you open mpir.sln, you should only compile code for the specific CPU. And then you compile the C++ wrapper (i.e. compile lib_mpir_p3 first, and then lib_mpir_cxx).

Edit: I just noticed another error from your original post. You need to rename the directory "mpir-2.6.0" to "mpir". The directory layout needs to be "<>\mpir\build.vc10"

Comment: I did. The projects that appears to me when I open: mpir.sln are: dll_mpir_core2,
dll_mpir_gc,
dll_mpir_k8, 
dll_mpir_nehalem,
lib_mpir_core2,
lib_mpir_cxx,
lib_mpir_gc,
lib_mpir_k8,
lib_mpir_nehalem. All these projects are x64 as the .py file shows. And my laptop is Win 32 bit. I believe it does not support x64. It is Intel core2. The problem is that I do not see any x32 project (such as P3) so I can build it.

Comment: Strange. After running mpir_config.py, and selecting "3", I have lib_mpir_p3 and dll_mpir_p3 available. Do this before opening mpir.sln. After compiling, make sure you check the new directory location I gave.

Comment: I just got that I have to pick an option. Sorry, I thought that it was listing what is supported. So, in my case, what is the suitable option for Intel Core2 Due?

Comment: Based on comments in mpir_config.py, I think p3mmx is recommended. BTW, please also see my edit about renaming "mpir-2.6.0" to just "mpir".

Comment: I built the intended version successfully. I copied: `mpir.lib` & `mpir.pdb` from `C:\c++\mpir\build.vc10\x64\Release` and the `xx` version from `C:\c++\mpir\build.vc10\Win32\Release`. I copied the headers from: `C:\c++\mpir\lib\64\Release` and the `xx` version from: `C:\c++\mpir\lib\Win32\Release`. I copied them to the VC `lib` and include files respectively. When I run my `vc++` code, I get:`error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'mpirxx.lib': No such file or directory c:\Users\e\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test4\test4\c1xx`. I added: mpir.lib mpirxx.lib to the proj. command line.

Comment: I am not sure if I copied from the correct location? Why my project can not see the two `lib `files ?

Comment: You can't mix x64 (64-bit) and Win32 (32-bit) components. You need to build the p3mmx version. It will work on a 32-bit Core2 system. The "Core2" option is only 64-bit. All the files you need should be found in mpir\lib\Win32\Release. Don't copy them from another location since they may get out-of-sync.

Comment: Win32 projects do not appear when I open mpir.sln even after putting the options in the python file.

Comment: When I run "C:\Python32\python.exe mpir_config.py" and enter "4" at the prompt, it definitely adds "lib_mpir_p3_p3mmx" entry to mpir.sln. Not sure why it's not working for you.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express. I could open Win32 library projects by using the older release of MPIR. But the problem still exist. I may copy the files mpit.h and mpitxx.h to a wrong directory. I am pasting them in: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include. The error message I get is: error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'mpirxx.lib': No such file or directory c:\Users\e\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\test5\test5\c1xx`. Which indicates that the files are not placed correctly. As I said, I configured my project command line to see these two files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with MPIR 2.6.0 and VS 2012. What I did to make MPIR work was to build lib_gc and lib_cxx, both with win32 and release mode. Because my c++ application is win32 console, this way it worked perfectly.

Becuase my windows is 64, I thought I had to build 64 versions, but turned out that I was wrong.