# Sparse Matrices and Large Integers in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, installation

I have basically spent all evening trying to find (and run) C/C++ packages that can handle large integers as well as large/sparse matrices.

After extensive reading, e.g. [How to build mpir-2.4.0 with Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6970558/how-to-build-mpir-2-4-0-with-visual-studio-2010), [Can not find mpirxx.h after building the mpir-2.6.0 library in vc++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110004/can-not-find-mpirxx-h-after-building-the-mpir-2-6-0-library-in-vc) and http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-to-install-and-run-gmp-on-windows-using-mpir/, I have finally managed to get MPIR to run in Visual Studio 2012. But I also need to do calcuations with large matrices.

After further research I came across linbox and LiDIA, but couldn't find any useful/understandable installation guidelines for Visual Studio under Windows. I am at my wit's end. Would somebody mind helping me out here? How do I get e.g. linbox to run? Or is it only possible under Linux...?

Comment: Library recommendation questions are subjective and usually closed on stackoverflow. However, I would recommend looking at [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/).

Comment: @DavidBrown Thanks for the tip, but I am not really looking for any other packages. What I need is a step-by-step instruction on how to install linbox (or Eigen for that matter), i.e. which files to compile (and how) and which h-file do I need to copy where, etc.